# Swift, why this local var is not released?

Tags: swift, automatic-ref-counting, rx-swift

I create a local var in a `awakeFromNib` function, use it inside a `UIView` animation block, but it is never released, why?

Here is the code (inside awakeFromNib in a UITableViewCell)

```
var fullPhotoDisposeBag = DisposeBag()
fullScreenImageView.rx.tapGesture().when(UIGestureRecognizerState.recognized).subscribe(onNext: { (tap) in

      UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.15, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            fullScreenImageView.frame = oldFullScreenFrame
      }, completion: { (finished) in
           fullScreenImageView.removeFromSuperview()
           let _ = fullPhotoDisposeBag //This line avoid early release, but retains too much...
      })
}, onDisposed:{
       print("disposed")
}).addDisposableTo(fullPhotoDisposeBag)
```

One clue is that the tableView is at the root of one tab of my app, so the UITableView is never deallocated thus the UITableViewCell is never deallocated due to the reusability.
But why would ARC keeps that variable? Used only in a function and a completion block?

PS: I currently use an optional DisposeBag that I set to nil in the completion block, but I don't understand why I need to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a retain cycle. My guess is the garbage collector won't release the local variable until the completion closure stops referencing it, and the completion closure is never released because it is owned by your local function.

My advise would be to move away this code from your UIView to your UIViewController, since that is where this sort of behavior should be defined.

Comment: Thanks, that’s what I was thinking. I’ll move the code to the viewController, unfortunately I guess there is no other way with rxSwift for such a case than to declare the disposeBag optional, force the unwrap when adding to disposeBag (I hate using “!”) then set the disposeBag to nil when the animation is done

Comment: What about just doing `fullPhotoDisposeBag = DisposeBag()` in the completion block? That should suffice to empty the original `DisposeBag`, breaking the retain cycle, while not requiring you to introduce an `Optional`.